# Chebyshev interpolation

Tags: ca.classical-analysis-and-odes, approximation-theory, interpolation

Let's define the n-th degree Chebyshev polynomials by

$$ T_{n} (x)=\cos(n\arccos(x)).$$

Find a polynomial $P$ such that

$$\mid y- P (x) \mid$$

is minimal, using the first three Chebyshev polynomials for the following data:

$$ \begin{bmatrix}
x & -1 & -0.5 & 0 & 0.5 & 1 \\
y & 0.6346 & 0.6565 & 1 & 1.5230 & 1.5756 
\end{bmatrix}.  $$

How could we manage to approach such a problem?

Comment: also posted on https://math.stackexchange.com/questions/2930280/minimal-error-chebyshev-interpolation

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Uniform approximation by polynomials on a finite set of points is studied in Section 1.3 of

> T.J. Rivlin, An introduction to the approximation of functions, Dover,
>   2003.

An explicit solution to your (non trivial) question is given on p.36 of that book.